# Wifi drops frequently while using Sidecar on Catalina macOS

Tags: macos, connection, wifi, macos-catalina

When using the Sidecar feature on the new macOS Cataline, my wifi drops for no reason. To fix this, I have to disconnect my Sidecar display and reconnect constantly. Been having this issue every time I use the Sidecar feature.

I am using Sidecar wirelessly.

Anyone experiencing this similar issue?

Comment: Sumit, stackoverflow is for programming problems. This question is off-topic here, but might be on topic on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/).